# Multirow line width

Tags: color, longtable, multirow, width

I'm having an issue with this code

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{longtable}{| p{4cm} | p{2cm} | p{7cm} |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{| p{14cm} |}{\cellcolor{lightgray} \centering \textbf{Iniciar sesión}}
    \\\hline
    \cellcolor{lightgray} \centering \textbf{Descripción} & \multicolumn{2}{| p{9cm} |}{}
    \\\hline
    \cellcolor{lightgray} \centering \textbf{Actor} & \multicolumn{2}{| p{9cm} |}{}
    \\\hline
    \cellcolor{lightgray} \centering \textbf{Pre-condición} & \multicolumn{2}{| p{9cm} |}{}
    \\\hline
    \cellcolor{lightgray} & \centering \textbf{Paso} & \textbf{}
    \\\cline{2-3}
    \cellcolor{lightgray} \centering \multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{Secuencia normal}} & \centering \textbf{1.} & 
    \\\hline
    \cellcolor{lightgray} \centering \textbf{Post-condición} & \multicolumn{2}{| p{9cm} |}{}
    \\\hline
    \cellcolor{lightgray} \centering \textbf{Excepciones} & \multicolumn{2}{| p{9cm} |}{}
    \\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{table}
```

[image: Table]

As shown the vertical line of "Secuencia normal" box is thiner than the other ones that are above and below, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: you can not have a longtable inside a table delete the outer environment

Comment: delete the `|` on the left pf every column except the first (otherwise you get two touching rules: to the right of one column and l;eft of the next)

Comment: You may simplify you code, replacing the tabular preamble: `{| p{4cm} | p{2cm} | p{7cm} |}` with `{|>{\columncolor{lightgray}} p{4cm} | p{2cm} | p{7cm} |}`, and removing `\cellcolor{lightgray}` from all rows except the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were doubling some vertical rules inside the `\multicolumn`s and this was giving you thicker rules:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{| >{\centering}p{4cm} | p{2cm} | p{7cm} |}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{| >{\centering}p{14cm} |}{\cellcolor{lightgray} \textbf{Iniciar sesión}}
    \\\hline
    \cellcolor{lightgray}  \textbf{Descripción} & \multicolumn{2}{ p{9cm} |}{}
    \\\hline
    \cellcolor{lightgray} \textbf{Actor} & \multicolumn{2}{ p{9cm} |}{}
    \\\hline
    \cellcolor{lightgray} \textbf{Pre-condición} & \multicolumn{2}{ p{9cm} |}{}
    \\\hline
    \cellcolor{lightgray} & \textbf{Paso} & \textbf{}
    \\\cline{2-3}
    \cellcolor{lightgray} \centering \multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{Secuencia normal}} & \centering \textbf{1.} & 
    \\\hline
    \cellcolor{lightgray}  \textbf{Post-condición} & \multicolumn{2}{ p{9cm} |}{}
    \\\hline
    \cellcolor{lightgray} \textbf{Excepciones} & \multicolumn{2}{ p{9cm} |}{}
    \\\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Remarks

- Don't use `longtable` inside `table`.
- I used the `>{...}` syntax from the `array` package to add `\centering` to the first column.
- The `booktabs` package can give you better looking tbales (with no vertical rules).